# How do you pronounce the ":" in Wede:i?

Tags: phonology, verdurian-languages

Looking at the zompist page for [Wede:i](http://www.zompist.com/wedei.html#Phonology), I don't see any instructions on how to pronounce the ":" that we see in the name of the language and other places.

Am I missing something? How are you supposed to pronounce the ":"?

Answer (score 14):

The phonology table shows it quite simply, it modifies the `e` to indicate that it is a long vowel. I don't know why the vowel table shows the dipthongs `a:i` and `a:u` but not `e:i` (or any others).

Note that although this may seem to be a common colon, [the actual IPA diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_(phonetics)) is two triangles, flat sides on the outside: U+02D0 `ː`. But as the colon doesn't have another meaning in the IPA and it's much easier to type, a lot of people just use it instead.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen that before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because a:i and a:u are the only actual (long) diphthongs, e:i is read as two syllables (which is allowed because it's word final)